# host multiple websites in default website IIS 7.5 using application?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

Can I host different host address web sites on port 80 in default website in IIS 7.5 by creating applications ? Or Do I need to create separate websites in IIS with port 80?

Any good documentation, please provide me. I need to host www.WebsiteA.com and www.WebsiteB.com on port 80. I was in the impression of  using single website host different websites.

Comment: you mean virtual directory or applications?

Comment: Use virtual directories. For example, let's say you have two sites `A` and `B` that you want to both host on port 80. Put them both as virtual directories, then you can reach them at `http://server/A` and `http://server/B`

Comment: But I don't that urls. I need it like this www.siteA.com and www.siteB.com. Different host addresses.

Comment: In that case, host them as separate sites, configure DNS for `siteA.com` and `siteB.com` to both point to your server, and then configure each site with Host Header Values in IFS.

Comment: If you want the same content to be served for both siteA.com and siteB.com then simply have both of those added to the single site's [Host Header entries](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx) and it will respond to either. Otherwise, you want 2 separate sites in IIS named accordingly with matching bindings/hostnames to serve independent content.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to look like this: `www.WebsiteA.com` and `www.WebsiteB.com` 
Then you have to create different websites.

Different applications are used in case you have the same host header and want your url be like: `www.WebsiteA.com/app1` and `www.WebsiteA.com/app2`

Here are some technet links that can give you more insight

Add a binding to a site IIS 7

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Configure a Host Header for a Web Site (IIS 7)

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Managing Sites in IIS 7

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771341(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771341%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)